# Gatsby/React Project wont recongnize ssr script tag cloudinary variable also tried with Helmet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, cloudinary

Gatsby/React Project wont recongnize ssr script tag cloudinary variable but if I open up the inspect tool and type cloudinary and hit enter the entire function is there. Even if I place cloudinary console log in a click event it still returns undefined, same with a useEffect.

Any Ideas why I can't access cloudinary.

Thanks ahead of time

Here is the ssr

```
import React from "react"

export const onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }, pluginOptions) => {
  setHeadComponents([
    <script
      key="cloudinary"
      src="https://widget.cloudinary.com/v2.0/global/all.js"
      type="text/javascript"
      async
    />,
  ])
}
```

Here is the entrie code of the page, I only have helmet there when I turn off the ssr part

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"

import Layout from "../components/layout"

import Footer from "../components/Footer"

import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"


const Concepts = ({ data, location }) => {
 


  const clickMe = () => {
    console.log(cloudinary) //returns undefined
  }


  return (
    <Layout location={location}>
      <Helmet>
        <script
          src="https://widget.cloudinary.com/v2.0/global/all.js"
          type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
      </Helmet>
  

      <button onClick={clickMe}>test</button>

      <Footer />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Concepts
```

The point of testing for cloudinary is because adding the button and this script was returning undefined.

```
var myWidget = cloudinary.createUploadWidget({
  cloudName: 'my_cloud_name', 
  uploadPreset: 'my_preset'}, (error, result) => { 
    if (!error && result && result.event === "success") { 
      console.log('Done! Here is the image info: ', result.info); 
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit what you are trying to achieve? What's the point of adding the cloudinary script? (I guess is for adding the upload images script but I don't want to base an answer on assumptions)

Comment: I added the code that wasn't working, which resulted in me testing it the way I was with onClick handler. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways of adding a `<script>` in your `<header>`, both setHeadComponents and <`Helmet>` are perfectly valid, in addition, if you inspect (as you said) the output code, it should appear. So that part looks perfect to me.

In your case, `cloudinary` is not defined because belongs to the `window` global object. Something like this should work:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Footer from "../components/Footer"
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"

const Concepts = ({ data, location }) => {
 
  const clickMe = () => {
    if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
    console.log(window.cloudinary) //
    let widget = window.cloudinary.createUploadWidget({ 
       cloudName: `your cloudName`,
       uploadPreset: `your upload preset`}, 
    (error, result) => {
      if (!error && result && result.event === "success") { 
      console.log(result.info.url); 
    }});
    widget.open() //
   } 
 }


  return (
    <Layout location={location}>
      <Helmet>
        <script
          src="https://widget.cloudinary.com/v2.0/global/all.js"
          type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
      </Helmet>
      <button onClick={clickMe}>test</button>
      <Footer />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Further resources:

- https://medium.com/@jon.glass82/using-the-cloudinary-upload-widget-with-react-js-c0854138cc29
- https://medium.com/@jordanmmartin/quickstart-guide-to-using-cloudinary-upload-widget-v2-in-react-4c4d9041d55e
- https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget#how_to_setup_and_integrate_the_upload_widget_into_your_site_or_app

Comment: oh thanks I will try this and report back. I know that Gatsby has a issue with the window object on build time, but I will test first.

Comment: so just for reference for gatsby build I needed to do this before the window ```const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined"

    if (!isBrowser) {
      return
    }```